# How to rename disk label with spaces in Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Hi i have a disk whose label is "Local Disk". I am performing some action and formatting that disk ,want to rename that disk label to "Local Disk" but i am getting error in below line because of space in Local and Disk. I writing below code for that

```
strOutput = ExecuteDiskPartCommand("Format fs=ntfs label=”Local Disk” quick") // Error

strOutput = ExecuteDiskPartCommand("Format fs=ntfs label=”LocalDisk” quick") // No Error
```

How  can i acheive this "Local Disk" in Vbscript?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need escaped quotes around "Local Disk":

```
strOutput = ExecuteDiskPartCommand("Format fs=ntfs label=""Local Disk"" quick")
```

Plus, I don't think space (alt-32) is allowed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832054.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
strOutput = ExecuteDiskPartCommand("Format fs=ntfs label= & Chr(34) & "Local Disk" & Chr(34) & "quick")

Comment: This just demonstrates that if you use Chr(34) - instead of "" in the literal - you risk errors like forgetting the " before the & or the space before the q.